# Locus of point at a fixed distance from midpoint of intercepts of a variable line segment with fixed distance

Tags: geometry, locus

> Let A and B be variable points on the x-axis and y-axis respectively such that the line segment AB is in the first quadrant and of a fixed length 2d. Let C be the mid-point of AB and P be a point such that
>
> (a) P and the origin are on the opposite sides of AB and,
>
> (b) PC is a line of length d which is perpendicular to AB.
>
> Find the locus of P.
>
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2020.pdf)

In this problem, I have drawn the figure containing the line AB and point P and everything. I have also named point as(h, k),thereby applying all suitable equations.Inspite of all that, it is getting clumsy.
Can anyone provide a elegant solution to it?

Comment: Could anyone do it

Comment: I found an elegant solution, but I would like to see your "clumsy" solution (and check that my work is correct). Do be warned that my solution is geometric, so you may need to translate the locus back to its coordinate form.

Comment: @player3236 I could not reach the solition....can you share your solution.... My approach is clumsy. It would be helpful if you can share your solution...the calculations are cumbersome.... And I don't know how to do that

Comment: I am also eager to see how this problen will go...can you share @player3236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = (x, 0), 0 \leq x \leq 2d$ and $\alpha = O\hat{A}B$ (note that $\cos\alpha = \frac{x}{2d}$). Then $B = \left(0, x \tan\alpha\right)$ and $C = (\frac{x}{2}, \frac{x\tan\alpha}{2})$. Because $P$ and the origin are on the opposite sides of $AB$, we define $\vec{v} = (\sin\alpha, \cos\alpha)$ so that $P = C + d\vec{v} = (\frac{x}{2} + d\sin\alpha, \frac{x\tan\alpha}{2} + d\cos\alpha)$.

Also, $\cos\alpha = \frac{x}{2d} \implies \sin\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{4d^2 - x^2}}{2d}$ and $\tan\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{4d^2 - x^2}}{x}$. Substituting in $P$, $P = \left(\frac{\sqrt{4d^2 - x^2} + x}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{4d^2 - x^2} + x}{2}\right)$: $P$ lies on $x=y$.

For the limits (remember that $0 \leq x \leq 2d$): $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{4d^2 - x^2} + x}{2}$ attains minimum at $x=2d$, with $f(2d) = d$ and maximum at $x=\sqrt2 d$, with $f(\sqrt2 d) = \sqrt2d$.

Therefore, locus of $P$ is the segment from $(d,d)$ to $(\sqrt2 d, \sqrt2 d)$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $\triangle APB$ is an isosceles right-angled triangle, hence $OAPB$ is cyclic.

[image]

Note that $\angle BAP = \angle BOP = 45^\circ$. Hence $P$ lies on the line $y=x$.

Now we need to find the range of the length of $OP$. Intuitively it cannot be too long or too short since $P$ is bounded in a circle of radius $d$ containing the origin.

By Ptolemy's Theorem: $AO \times PB + AP \times OB = AB \times OP$.

Hence $AO \times \sqrt2 d+ \sqrt2d\times OB = 2d \times OP$, giving $\sqrt 2OP = AO+ OB$.

We have $AO^2 + OB^2 = 4d^2$. By letting $x = AO$ and considering the function $x + \sqrt{4d^2 - x^2}$ or otherwise (there should be a better way to do this), we see that the maximum occurs when $AO = OB = \sqrt 2d$ and the minimum occurs when $AO$ or $OB = 0$, giving the range:

$$\sqrt 2 d \le OP \le 2d$$

hence the locus is the line segment connecting the points $(d,d)$ and $(\sqrt 2 d, \sqrt 2d)$.

Comment: The answer is absolutely right

Comment: Where did $x^2 + \sqrt{4p^2 - x^2}$ come from?